# plot is not defined

Tags: python

I started to use matplotlib library to get a graph. 
But when I use "plot(x,y)" it returns me that "plot is not defined".

To import , I used the following command:

`from matplotlib import *`

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 41):

Change that import to

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
```

Note that this style of imports (`from X import *`) is generally discouraged. I would recommend using the following instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use a function form a package or module in python you have to import and reference them.
For example normally you do the following to draw 5 points( [1,5],[2,4],[3,3],[4,2],[5,1]) in the space:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],"bx")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

In your solution

```
from matplotlib import*
```

This imports the package matplotlib and "plot is not defined" means there is no plot function in matplotlib you can access directly, but instead if you import as

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
plot([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],"bx")
show()
```

Now you can use any function in matplotlib.pyplot without referencing them with matplotlib.pyplot.

I would recommend you to name imports you have, in this case you can prevent disambiguation and future problems with the same function names. The last and clean version of above example looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],"bx")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` works for me in jupyter

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'plot' by 'plt'
instead of:
plot.xlabel('Índice de masa corporal (IMC)')
put:
plt.xlabel('Índice de masa corporal (IMC)')

Answer (score -1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.rc('axes', labelsize=14)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

```
from matplotlib import pyplot 
pyplot.rc('axes', titlesize=18) 
pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to a different question (note the different error messages).

Comment: It doesn't work for you because you imported `matplotlib` and for some reason tried to use `matlablib`... I don't see how that answers the question...