# plot, figure, and title function error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having trouble plotting my results in Python, both in Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7 (both 64bit). As a simple comparison I did:

```
from tvb.simulator.lab import * 
--> to import (among others) numpy as np and matplotlib.pyplot.

x = [1,2,3]

plot(x)
--> NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
```

When I looked up this error ([plot is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532903/plot-is-not-defined)) and followed these instructions, I get this result

```
matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f8e31754dd0
```

without output...

Anyone who knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your import (`tvb.simulator.lab`) does

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

then you have to call `plot` like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x)
```

BUT, you could also reimport it in your script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and then use the alias `plt` (thats farely common):

```
plt.plot(x)
```